# What are the "wavelet planes" in a Stationary Wavelet Transform?

Tags: wavelet, wavelet-transform, pywavelets

Several articles, like [Detection of superimposed periodic signals using wavelets](https://academic.oup.com/mnras/article/333/2/365/1019203) and [À Trous Wavelet Decomposition Applied to Image Edge Detection](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/10824000109480563) mention "**wavelet planes**" but I do not understand what these are.

In [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_wavelet_transform) and in a [python package](https://pywavelets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/swt-stationary-wavelet-transform.html) to calculate wavelet decomposition, there is no reference to "wavelet planes". Are these the list of approximation and details coefficients (such as the output of the function on the package)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because off topic

Comment: @Graviton, I do not know how to close it. I thought it was on topic because I wanted to use the python package to obtain the "wavelet planes" but I do not understand if the output of the function is what I wanted. But if it is not appropriate, I will ask it in the Mathematics website.

Answer (score 0):

Explains it in the article it's been linked:

> The algorithm can decompose an image (or a signal) into an approximate
> signal and a detail signal at a scale, the detail signal is called a
> wavelet plane, which is same as the original image in dimension.

---

Basically Wavelet is an algorithmic technique (similar to trees not exactly though) that decomposes 1-D or 2-D time-series data, mapping them into low-frequency and high-frequency data using convolution theories.

- Those high frequency data is called Details or here "wavelet plane" (never actually heard this term before).
- The low-frequency data is generally referred to as Approximations.

[image]

- The above decomposition is one of the existing one.

#### Example of mapping in an image:

[image]

#### [Another Example](https://pywavelets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/2d-decompositions-overview.html)

[image]

- [Ref 1](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/The-Lena-image-decomposed-by-square-wavelet-transform-built-from-the-Daubechies_fig3_1957226)
- [Ref 2](https://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S0370-44672010000200020)